# S3 for both data+static site VS s3 for data and static hosting service (like Netlify) for static site

Tags: amazon-s3, deployment, gatsby

I have a static React site built with Gatsby, and the web app needs to retrieve audio files from a database and play them. The site is already deployed on Netlify, and the audio files are in an S3 bucket (configured with an Cloudfront OAI for access).

But I've been wondering, would it better to just host both the site and the audio files on S3? If this were the case, then I believe the site wouldn't have to make any HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the best way is to use CloudFront and 2 buckets, 1 for the html/js/css/etc files, and the other for the audio. You can configure your own domain name for the CloudFront distribution (with Route53 and ACM).

One thing is CloudFront uses paths to route between the origins (the 2 buckets in your case). You can set up 2 cache behaviors, one with a path pattern of, let's say, /audio/*, the other one to *. This way, /index.html, /app.js, etc. will go to your webapp, and /audio/file.mp4 will go to the audio bucket.

I'm wondering what you mean by "wouldn't have to make any HTTPS requests". You should *only* allow HTTPS requests.